# MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=text/html

Tags: java, spring, rest, jersey-2.0, grizzly

I am trying to integrate Jersey 2.22.2 with Jsp and Spring. I am facing some difficulties making it work. I am using Servlet 3.0 style Java configuration. I am attaching the code.

```
@Path("spider")
@Template
@Component
@Data
@Slf4j
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class DashboardController {

@Autowired
private SpiderWeb dashboard;

private Map<String, Spider> spiderMap = new HashMap<String, Spider>();

@GET
@Path("/jsp/dashboard")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public Response process(@QueryParam("name") final String name,
                        @QueryParam("timeLapse") final Long timeLapse) {
    if(spiderMap.isEmpty()) {
        for (Spider spider : dashboard.getSpiders()) {
            spiderMap.put(spider.getName(), spider);
        }
    }
    if (name != null && timeLapse != null && spiderMap.containsKey(name)) {
       log.info("re-index  '" + name + "'");
       spiderMap.get(name).trigger(timeLapse);
    }

    return Response.ok().entity(new Viewable("/dashboard", dashboard)).build();
  }
}
```

The Java config class that creates the WebappContext and registers the JspMvcFeature class and the provider packages.

```
package com.sky.search.spider.api;

import com.xxx.search.stack.http.StackApplication;
import com.xxx.search.stack.http.StackHttpServer;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.ServletRegistration;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.WebappContext;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerProperties;
import org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;

public class SpiderStackHttpServer extends StackHttpServer{


public SpiderStackHttpServer(StackApplication application, boolean   enableJmx) {
    super(application, enableJmx);
}


@Override
public void deployServletContext(HttpServer server) {

    WebappContext context = new WebappContext("WebappContext", "");
    context.setInitParameter("contextClass","org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext");

    ServletRegistration registration = context.addServlet("ServletContainer" , ServletContainer.class);
    registration.setInitParameter(ServerProperties.PROVIDER_PACKAGES, "com.sky.search.spider.web");
    registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    registration.setInitParameter("jersey.config.server.mvc.templateBasePath.jsp","/WEB-INF/jsp");
    registration.setInitParameter("contextClass" , "org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext");
    //registration.setInitParameter("contextConfigLocation" , "com.sky.search.spider.spring.ApiConfig");
    registration.setInitParameter("jersey.config.server.provider.classnames", "org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.jsp.JspMvcFeature");
    registration.addMapping("/jsp/dashboard/*");

    context.addListener(ContextLoaderListener.class);

    context.deploy(server);

}
```

}

We are using our own Custom Java class to start the HttpServer

```
public StackHttpServer(StackApplication application, boolean     enableJmx) {
    GrizzlyHttpContainer container = new    GrizzlyHttpContainerProvider().createContainer(GrizzlyHttpContainer.class, application.getConfiguration());
    this.server = createHttpServer(application.getUri(), container, false, null, false);
    this.server.getServerConfiguration().setJmxEnabled(enableJmx);
    configureThreads(server);
    try {
        server.start();
        deployServletContext(server);
    } catch (final IOException ex) {
        server.shutdownNow();
        throw new ProcessingException(LocalizationMessages.FAILED_TO_START_SERVER(ex.getMessage()), ex);
    }
   }
```

So when I start the server , I am getting the following error.

> 2016-02-23 18:38:05,186 ERROR
>   [org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor] -
>   MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=text/html, type=class
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.Viewable, genericType=class
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.Viewable.

I read in the Jersey website that Servlet 3.0 style won't work.
https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d0e15405
But I think it might be outdated and I would request your help in this regard.